# AWS security group settings

Tags: security, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ssh, redhat

Currently, I connect from my pc to a RedHat instance, and from this Redhat, i connect to Ubuntu. 
The thing is, I cannot manage to connect to Ubuntu, I have a timeout error.

In the security group of Ubuntu, I put the following settings in inbound:

`Type=SSH 
Protocol=TCP 
Port=22 
Source=PublicIPofRedHat/32`

And from Redhad, I connect using 
`ssh -i ~/.ssh/ubuntu.pem ubuntu@PublicIPofRedHat`

This setting does not work, but I would like to know why.

I changed this setting and put SecurityGroupOfRedHat instead of IP and it works. 
But with this setting, it means that any instance within this security group can also access to my Ubuntu (which I dont want), right ?

Could you please help with these settings ? Explain me what is wrong and how could I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the redhat *private* IP and that should make it work.

Generally, connecting security group to security group is better (than including IPs in the security group). It's less brittle. If other instances are in the same SG as the redhat instance, you probably need to use more specific security groups.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It is working with the private IP. But I dont understand why I can use the private and not the public one ? what is the difference ? Moreover, the private may change if we restart the session, right ?

Comment: Think of private as "inside an AZ" communication. You should prefer intra communication. Private IP only changes on restart (I think- a reboot should be okay).

Answer (score 0):

You can use security groups as sources for other security groups instead of IP addresses. For example, the security group for Ubuntu could have the following inbound rule:

```
Type=SSH
Protocol=TCP
Port=22
Source=SecurityGroupOfRedHat
```

This has the advantage of not hard coding IP addresses into you security groups. Instead, your security groups refer to each other. This is better because the private IP of an instance can change if it is stopped and started again. If that happens you will need to update all of your security groups.